# Making a Post request to Github API for creating issue is not working

Tags: node.js, github-api

I have been trying to make this post request to the github api for the last couple of days, but unfortunately the response is coming back as "bad message"

here is the piece of code we are sending in the post request using https request in node -

This is the post data

```
var issueData = JSON.stringify({
  "title":title,
  "body":comment
});
```

This is the options file

```
var options = {
  host: 'api.github.com',
  path: '/repos/sohilpandya/katasohil/issues?access_token='+sessions.token,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
  },
  method: 'POST'
};
```

This is the https request

```
var requestaddIssue  = https.request(options, function(responseFromIssues){
  responseFromIssues.setEncoding('utf8');
  responseFromIssues.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('>>>>chunk>>>>>',chunk);
    issueBody += chunk;
  });
  responseFromIssues.on('end',function(issueBody){
    console.log(issueBody);
  });
});
requestaddIssue.write(issueData);
requestaddIssue.end();
```

I have tried another approach where the authentication token for the user is in the header as

```
'Authentication': 'OAuth '+ sessions.token (where we are storing token inside sessions)
```

But the chunk response always seems to come back with the following in the console log.

```
{
 "message": "Not Found",
 "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"
}
```

I have tried the same in apigee and it seems to work ok and returns to correct response. Hoping someone can find the minor error in the code above that is causing this bad message error.

Comment: Have you gotten this to work with any other requests? Also have you considered using a module to create the requests like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or even just using [node-github](https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github) ?

Comment: @GrimurD I have got it working with a get request to retrieve some user data. Usually I do use the request module, but tried to break it down just to find the bug.

Comment: You should probably log the outgoing request using something like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make sure the request looks right. There must be something wrong with the request since you're getting 404 back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Except the `issueBody` variable is not defined in the snippets you posted, the code is correct. I tried it using a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

The error you get appears because you need to add a [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) with power to open issues.

I tried the `repo` and `public_repo` scopes and they are both working. Note that `repo` has access to private repositories. Here you can see the [list of scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).

If you're using OAuth, then you you should have an url looking like this:

> `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client-id>&scope=public_repo&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>`

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be woking after adding the scope. :)