# Create Issue in github through api using nodejs and request: response is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api

I have read this issue: [Making a Post request to Github API for creating issue is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33390666/5619373) but I am looking for support using the request module. I've read the github documentation, but I'm having a hard time translating their curl examples to javascript.

This is part of a larger attempt at slack/github integration with slash commands. Right now I am just trying to submit a generic request to github. When I log the body of the response, it is 'undefined'.

I would prefer not to use a github wrapper because I would like to understand what I am doing and why it isn't working better.

Any help for this noob is much appreciated.

EDIT: Made changes as suggest in comments
Error is ECONNREFUSED
I'm getting an error when I try to log the response status because response is undefined.

```
    request({
    "url":"http://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues",
    "method":"POST",
    "headers": {"Authorization": "auth token"},
    "body": JSON.stringify({ title: "Found a bug", body: "I'm having a problem  this." })
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure that callback function admits those 3 parameters (`err, response, body`)?

Comment: Your `url` parameter does not look right either: 1) it must be `https` 2) it's not clear why you add a token to the url (it's definitely wrong)

Comment: Try to log that `err` parameter as well: `if (err) console.log(err);`

Comment: Did you check `response.statusCode`? Also, you aren't submitting a JSON body. Perhaps you meant `body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'Found a bug', body: "I'm having a problem with this." })`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, the error is ECONNREFUSED so I am focusing now on getting the authorization correct. @zerkms, I was trying anything to send the token and had seen it used in the URL so gave it a shot. I removed it now.

Comment: @zerkms is right then, start fixing your `url` param

Comment: try using https

Answer (score 1):

Among the other issues as outlined in the comments (thank you everyone). In my URL I had http instead of https.

DOH